# Read CSS literal value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this CSS property in style.css

```
.beatBlock {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}

.beatBlock.beatBlockShow {
    height: 150px;
}
```

I want to be able to read the height literal value written in .beatBlockShow and retrieve the value `150` (or `150px`, it doesn't matter).
The problem is, I can't do the following :

```js
let beatBlock = document.createElement('div');
beatBlock.classList = 'beatBlock';
beatBlock.classList.add('beatBlockShow');

// of course it will give me a height between 0 and 150, because of the transition property
const literalHeight = beatBlock.offsetHeight; 
console.log(literalHeight);
```

```css
.beatBlock {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}

.beatBlock.beatBlockShow {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="beatBlock">
<div class="beatBlockShow"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this ? 
Thank you

Comment: `beatBlock.style.transition = ""`, _then_ calculate the height.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/an-introduction-and-guide-to-the-css-object-model-cssom/#article-header-id-8

Comment: you can also use `document.styleSheets` , iterate over it & get the value.

Comment: Do you need this value immediately, or will it suffice to get it after the transition has ended (you can listen to `transitionend` events on the element)

Comment: @Phillip I need this value immediately

Comment: I found the way to solve it (sorry, cannot answer my own question yet) :
`
// find needed literal CSS values
literalValue = "", literalValue2 = "";
for (let styleSheet of document.styleSheets) {
    let allRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
    for (let rule of allRules) {
        if (rule.selectorText === '.yourClass') {
            literalValue = parseInt(rule.style.height, 10);
        } else if (rule.selectorText === '#yourId') {
            literalValue2 = parseInt(rule.style.height, 10);
        }
    }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

You can append the div to your body (so that its styles can be evaluated) and then use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the height of the element:

```js
let beatBlock = document.createElement('div');
beatBlock.classList.add('beatBlock');
beatBlock.classList.add('beatBlockShow');

document.body.appendChild(beatBlock); // add div to DOM

const literalHeight = getComputedStyle(beatBlock).getPropertyValue('height');

console.log(literalHeight);
```

```css
.beatBlock {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}

.beatBlock.beatBlockShow {
  height: 150px;
}
```